# Can't get another tkinter frame to be displayed when a certain condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make an instant messenger program which works over a network drive and used some code by @Bryan Oakley to switch between tkinter frames. The first frame is supposed to be an entry for a usesrname which is saved in a txt file. I want to skip this frame if my program detects that the username has already been saved once. however I get the following error when trying to do so.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Douglas Rouse\Google Drive\Python\New structure.py", line 260, in <module>
    app = ChatApp()
  File "C:\Users\Douglas Rouse\Google Drive\Python\New structure.py", line 73, in __init__
    frame = StartPage(self.container, self)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas Rouse\Google Drive\Python\New structure.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.check_user()
  File "C:\Users\Douglas Rouse\Google Drive\Python\New structure.py", line 144, in check_user
    ChatApp.show_frame(ChatApp,[PageOne])
  File "C:\Users\Douglas Rouse\Google Drive\Python\New structure.py", line 106, in show_frame
    self.frame = self.frames[cont]
AttributeError: type object 'ChatApp' has no attribute 'frames'
```

I am fairly new to python so an explanation of where exactly I went wrong would be appreciated!

```
class ChatApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Messenger")

        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.grid()
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(self.container, self)
        self.frame_ = PageOne(self.container, self)
        frame1 = BanPage(self.container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        self.frames[PageOne] = self.frame_
        self.frames[BanPage] = frame1

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frame_.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        #ban()




    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        usrlabel = ttk.Label(self, text="Input Username", font=LARGE_FONT)
        usrlabel.grid(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.usrentry = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.usrentry.grid()
        StartPage.uu = self.usrentry.get()

        #command within button cant throw args to funcs. Use lambda to throw those args to the func instead
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",command=
                            lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid()
        Button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "test",command = self.save_user)
        Button2.grid()
        self.check_user() 

    def save_user(self,*args):
        usr = open("user.txt","a")
        self.public_usr = open("publicusr.txt","a")
        self.public_usr.write(self.usrentry.get())
        usr.write(self.usrentry.get())
        self.usrentry.delete(0, 'end')

    def check_user(self):
        usrcount=0
        with open ("user.txt","rb") as usr:
            for line in usr:
                usrcount+=1
            if usrcount == 1:
                ChatApp.show_frame(ChatApp,[PageOne])
                print(usrcount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is causing the problem:

```
ChatApp.show_frame(ChatApp,[PageOne])
```

You call `show_frame` not on an *instance* of `ChatApp`, but on the *class object* itself. The class does not have the attribute, which is why you get the error "'ChatApp' has no attribute 'frames'"

You cannot call `show_frame` on the class, you must call it on an instance of the class. In your case, the instance is passed in as `controller` which you need to save so that you can use it later.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args):
        self.controller = controller
        ...

    def check_user(self):
        ...
            if usrcount == 1:
                self.controller.show_frame(PageOne)
                ...
```

I think you will also have the problem that `show_frame` is being called before it is anything other than an empty dictionary. That's because you call `check_user` immediately when `StartPage` is created, which happens before you insert anything into `self.frames`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The explanation was very helpful. You were right about the empty dictionary I attempted to solve that but I imagine the etiquette dictates that i ask that in another question after trying to figure it out myself. Thank you very much for your help.